# How do I add a "something.a" library file to my C++ Android Gradle project?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I have a library called `somelibrary/lib/c++/armeabi-v7a/libsomelibrary.a`. How do I add it to the Gradle files in my Android project?

Obviously the library also contains the headers under `somelibrary/include/somelibrary/*.h` but that's the easy part because I can just add a line `cppFlags.addAll(['-I' + file('somepath/somelibrary/include')])` to my `build.gradle`.

But how do I also add the .a file to the project so that the linking works on all binary formats, not only armeabi-v7a but also arm64-v8a, armeabi and x86? The library contains versions of the .a file for all those binary formats. And in addition to that, it also contains versions for two different c++ standard libraries: "c++" and "gnustl". I don't have the source code of the library.

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-link-a-c-library-with-another-library-file-that-i-know-the-path-of/7241/3 `.lib` and `.a` are same thing across platform windows and linux

Comment: I am not sure if this can help you since it uses the gradle experimental plugin. In the gradle experimental you can directly add a dependency on a static or shared prebuilt library: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what gradle version are using, in case of build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'

In app build.gradle file:

- Firstly define your library repository

  ```
  repositories {
      libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
          your_lib {
             headers.srcDir "${your_lib_path}/include"
             binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
             staticLibraryFile =   file("${your_lib_path}/your_library.a")
              }
          }
    }
  }
  ```
- Define your ndk-module

  ```
    android.ndk 
    {
      moduleName = "your_ndk_module"
      platformVersion = 9
      toolchain "gcc"
      debuggable true
      cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
      cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
      stl = "gnustl_static" 
    }
  ```
- define library sources

  ```
  android.sources {

  main {

      jni {
           dependencies {
                        library "your_lib" linkage "static"
               }                  
          }
      }
   }
  ```
- define your product flavours

  ```
   android.productFlavors 
     {


                  create("arm") {
                      ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
                      ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi')}".toString())
                      ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])

                  }
                  create("arm7") {
                      ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                      ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a')}".toString())
                      ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])

                  }
                  create("arm8") {
                      ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
                      ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a')}".toString())
                      ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])
                  }
   }
  ```

Whole code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

def your_lib_path = file(project(':app').projectDir).absolutePath + "/your_lib_path"
model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            your_lib {
                headers.srcDir "${your_lib_path}/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("${your_lib_path}/your_library.a")
                }
            }
      }
  }
  //define your ndk-module: 
  android.ndk {
       moduleName = "your_ndk_module"
       platformVersion = 9
       toolchain "gcc"
       debuggable true
       cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
       cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
       stl = "gnustl_static" // Which STL library to use: gnustl or stlport
       }
  //define your android sources
  android.sources {
       main {
           jni {
               dependencies {
                   library "your_lib" linkage "static"
               }
           }
       }
   }

//define your product flavours: 
android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])

        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])

        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_lib"])
        }
    }

  }
```

You will have to modify your gradle file according to your gradle version.

Hope, this helps.

Cheers.

Unai.

Comment: Thanks, that probably is a perfect answer. The only problem is just that Android Studio just switched to CMake with c++ and this doesn't help anymore...